# Differences in running vim via command line vs. running it in the vim editor

Tags: vim, ex

I am trying to process a series of files.  I have noticed that there are discrepancies in running a particular command from the command line (i.e. `ex` mode).  E.g.

```
$cat poo.txt
big
red
dog
small
black
cat

$vim -c "2,$g/^dog/d|wq" poo.txt

$cat poo.txt
big
small
black
cat
```

It appears that `2,$g/^dog/d|wq` has deleted the lines with `red` and `dog`.  This confuses me because the command should : start on line 2 (going to EOF) and delete all lines beginning with `dog`.  In this instance, I'd expect the output to be:

```
$ cat poo.txt 
big
red
small
black
cat
```

In fact, if I try this in the vim editor this is the exact behavior that is observed.

QUESTION: What is cause of the discrepancy between the `vim -c` version and the `vim` version of running this command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to replace the double quotes with single quotes to prevent your shell from expanding `$g`. From `man bash`:

```
Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of all
characters within the  quotes,  with the  exception  of  $,  `, \, and, 
when history expansion is enabled, !.
```

Currently, your shell expands `$g` inside your string, as if it was an environment variable. But it's probably not defined, thus expands into an empty string. So, even though you've typed:

```
vim -c "2,$g/^dog/d|wq" poo.txt
```

Vim doesn't receive the command:

```
2,$g/^dog/d|wq
```

... but:

```
2,/^dog/d|wq
```

This command deletes all the lines from the one whose address is `2`, to the next one which starts with `dog` (in your case it's the 3rd line). Then, it saves and quit.

But even if you replace the quotes, there's still a problem in your command.
From `:h :bar`:

```
These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
followed by another Vim command:

...
:global
...
```

The bar is interpreted by `:g` as a part of its argument, not as a command termination. In your case, it means that whenever it finds a line starting with `dog`, it will delete it, then immediately save and quit. So, if there are several `dog` lines, only the first one will be deleted, because `:g` will have saved and quit after processing the 1st one.

You need to hide `|wq` from `:g`, either by wrapping the global command inside a string and executing it with `:execute`, or by moving `wq` in another `-c {cmd}`. All in all, you could try:

```
vim -c 'exe "2,\$g/^dog/d" | wq' poo.txt
```

or

```
vim -c '2,$g/^dog/d' -c 'wq' poo.txt
```

or

```
vim -c '2,$g/^dog/d' -cx poo.txt
```